# Django: apply validator at model level instead of column level

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

Let's say I have the following Django model:

```
class PersonClub(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("person", "club", "year")
```

I need to apply a validator at the model level that enforces this rule:

> A person can belong to only 3 different clubs in a given year.

What's the best way to do this? I imagine my validator should look something like this, but I have no idea where to put it:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

def validate_annual_clubs_per_person(obj):
    count = PersonClub.objects.filter(person=obj.person, year=obj.year).count()
    if count >= 3:
        raise ValidationError(
            _("%(person)s has exceeded max clubs for %(year)s"),
            params={"person": obj.person, "year": obj.year},
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can put validation in models.py and apply validation for a field

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

def validate_annual_clubs_per_person(obj):
    count = PersonClub.objects.filter(person=obj.person, year=obj.year).count()
    if count >= 3:
        raise ValidationError(
            _("%(person)s has exceeded max clubs for %(year)s"),
            params={"person": obj.person, "year": obj.year},
        )


class PersonClub(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, validators=[validate_annual_clubs_per_person])
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("person", "club", "year")
```

Comment: This doesn't work because field validators just take the filed value: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/#writing-validators. I need need the value of multiple fields.